# AutoCompleteTextView not working properly in Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to put Autocomplete text view in dialog, but I am getting error on adaptor.
I have created a new class extended by dialog and written following code:

```
AutoCompleteTextView textViewCountry = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(com.example.FindItNear.R.id.autocomplete_radius);    
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,com.example.FindItNear.R.layout.list_item, RADIUS);    --> error here no constructor found
         textViewCountry.setAdapter(adapter);


    static final String[] RADIUS = new String[] 

 {
    "1",
    "5",
    "10",
    "25",
    "100",
    "125",
    "200",
    "250",
    "500",
    "750",
    "1000",
    "1250",
    "1500"
    };
```

When I run same code on activity it works fine, but in dialog it won't.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: even i have used second parameter of arrayadaptor as
android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line
but still getting error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the view you created for the Dialog. You should have something that looks like this.

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);
final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null); 
AutoCompleteTextView textViewCountry = (AutoCompleteTextView) textEntryView.findViewById(com.example.FindItNear.R.id.autocomplete_radius);
```

Notice the textEntryView.findViewById(...)